# Double mach reflection at a inclined wedge

Tags: finite-difference, fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, finite-volume, navier-stokes

I am running into a strange problem when solving the 2D compressible Euler equations on a inclined wedge. To elaborate, my top boundary condition seems to emitting some type of instability.  I have tried using Neumann BCs for the u,v velocities, but the issue still persists.

I am using a 2nd-order finite volume method on a curvilinear mesh (structured grid).  My flux scheme is the Roe scheme with the Harten entropy fix.  I have attached a movie that illustrates the problem.

I was curious if someone has any thoughts.

[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/sev3o7olhqqx7h7/animation.mp4?dl=0

Comment: That looks like a shock instability which some schemes can suffer from. Can you try HLL flux which does not suffer from such problems, or even Rusanov flux.

Comment: I don't want to be too nosy, ..but what kind of application is this for? A Mach 10 shock in a confined space?:-)

Comment: I was able to implement the Rusanov flux.  What I have found is that I need approximately double the number grids in the X direction than the Y for the instability to not occur.  What I find strange is I have fully validated my code on an oblique shock over a ramp along with flow over a forward facing ramp.